# Save data to SharePoint list from external website

Tags: external-data

I have a web page running locally on my machine which hosts a bunch of forms for different requests, built using HTML/CSS/JS (AngularJS). I want to export that data to a SharePoint list when a user submits a form. Is this possible? The data consists of simple text inputs, dropdowns, and radio buttons. Some forms also have file uploads and one of them is only a file upload. I want to be able to upload the completed form data to the SharePoint list that's been created so that the results of all forms are accessible there.

Alternatively, can I create a SharePoint form and just embed that into my web page so that the SharePoint form pops up and gets saved to the list automatically? I don't see an option to get the embedded form code.

I have no prior experience with SharePoint so I'm not sure what the best route is, but the main focus is to connect my website's HTML/JS forms to a SharePoint list that's set up so that the data is saved there when forms are submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Without a bit more info of your specific requirements or setup it's difficult to recommend a particular solution.

If you're using sharepoint 2013 onwards, it provides a REST API endpoint for performing CRUD operations on lists. I would think this is the simplest method for an external Javascript based application as you can simply make a POST to the endpoint URL with the form data.

[Check out the MSDN docs for more info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)

I've also developed for sharepoint 2010 which lets you use the deprecated list services API, and the JSOM (Javascript Object Model) to work with sharepoint lists but I'm not sure that these would work for an application external to a sharepoint site as I believe they rely on libraries that are part of sharepoint.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll check out the REST API as I'm using SharePoint 2016 I believe, 2013 at the least. I have updated the question to include some specifics about my forms. Would the POST request handle file uploads? As I don't see documentation for that.

Comment: Using the REST API from an external website will result in a cors error